# Rails: image_tag doesn't append timestamp of image's last change (to force refresh instead of cache when loading page)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, carrierwave, browser-cache

I use Carrierwave to do file uploads in my Rails app.

When replacing an already uploaded image, the browser still renders the cached original image to the user. Only after hard-refreshing (Cmd-Shift-R on Mac) it renders the new one.

I read here ([Stop images from caching in Rails and browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1915617/stop-images-from-caching-in-rails-and-browser)) that Rails would attach the image's "last updated" timestamp to the URL, but it seems it doesn't in my app:

[image: Screenshot]

Maybe this changed meanwhile (the mentioned post is from 2009)? And how would that be fixed today? Thank you.

Comment: Am I the only one facing such problems?

Comment: The line of code have `image_tag` may help to debug, so it's better to add that line of code.

Answer (score 2):

`image_tag` uses `asset_path` to calculate final image path (in case it is from asset pipeline), but neither of those add cache buster timestamp.

When image is in asset pipeline and asset digests are enabled - a checksum will be added to file name by asset compilation. For uploaded images it's a task of your image uploading library or yourself.

For example (popular in the past) library paperclip used to save image timestamp in `<attachment>_updated_at` attribute and add it to generated links.

For carrierwave it's possible to include timestamp in [file name at upload](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/wiki/How-to:-Use-a-timestamp-in-file-names) like:

```rb
class PhotoUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  def filename
    @name ||= "#{timestamp}-#{super}" if original_filename.present? and super.present?
  end

  def timestamp
    var = :"@#{mounted_as}_timestamp"
    model.instance_variable_get(var) or model.instance_variable_set(var, Time.now.to_i)
  end
end
```

Or make it generate unique filenames by some other algorithm.
Anyway using original user-provided filename in your storage is usually not a good idea from security point of view (for example someone can upload `nasty_xss_hack.html`).

Other option - is to add timestamp yourself, model's `updated_at.to_i` is not ideal (usually model is updated more othed than the image), but will have the job done.